# Show a preview image of an HTML5 <input type="file"> selected image file

Tags: jquery, html, image

sorry if question is wrong ,

i want to `display` particular **`image`** in **`img`** tag when `<input type=file>`.

```js
$(':input[type=file]').change( function(event) {
 var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
 $(this).closest("img").attr('src',tmppath);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1">
    <font color="#FF0000">For best view upload only <b>200*250</b></font><div class="clear"></div>
    <img src="" id="img1" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px"><br>
<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2">
    <font color="#FF0000">For best view upload only <b>200*250</b></font><div class="clear"></div>
    <img src="" id="img2" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px"><br>
<input type="file" id="file3" name="file3">
    <font color="#FF0000">For best view upload only <b>200*250</b></font><div class="clear"></div>
    <img src="" id="img3" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px">
```

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bf7e39jk/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this : You have to use `.next()` instead of `.closest()` because next is used to find next element and closest is used to find matching parent element. see below code

```js
$(':input[type=file]').change( function(event) {
 var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
 $(this).next("img").attr('src',tmppath);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1">
<img src="" id="img1" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px"><br>
<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2">
<img src="" id="img2" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px"><br>
<input type="file" id="file3" name="file3">
<img src="" id="img3" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px">
```

More Information on **[.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** and **[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

**EDIT**: As OP have changed html structure, I have made some changes in my answer as shown below.
make group of input and image elements by putting it into div and make required changes in script.

```js
$(':input[type=file]').change( function(event) {
 var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    //get parent using closest and then find img element
 $(this).closest("div").find("img").attr('src',tmppath);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1"><br>
<font color="#FF0000">For best view upload only <b>200*250</b></font><div class="clear"></div>
<img src="" id="img1" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px"><br>
</div>
<div>
<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2"><br>
<font color="#FF0000">For best view upload only <b>200*250</b></font><div class="clear"></div>
<img src="" id="img2" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px"><br>
</div>
<div>
<input type="file" id="file3" name="file3"><br>
<font color="#FF0000">For best view upload only <b>200*250</b></font><div class="clear"></div>
<img src="" id="img3" class="img1" height="100px" width="100px">
</div>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: Hello @Bhushan can you help me again

Comment: i have made some changes in my code and now i want solution related to it

Comment: please post it as new question and provide jsfiddle if possible

Comment: You can group the input and images by wrapping them into `div` so that `div` element will be parent. Then use closest to get parent and use `find` to get image and change its src value. See [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/bf7e39jk/3/). So when you add remove any element in future it won't affect your code :)

Comment: happy to help you :)